# Jenkins + Phing: Build Failure - can't find build.xml

Tags: apache, jenkins, plesk, phing

Trying to set up Jenkins on one of my servers for the first time and think I might be missing something.

Jenkins 1.545
Phing 2.6.1

Jenkins builds give me the following output.

```
Building in workspace /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs
looking for '/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/build.xml' ... 
looking for '/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/build.xml' ... 
looking for 'build.xml' ... 
buildfile 'build.xml' not found.
Build step 'Invoke Phing targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I run my build.xml on it's own it works fine.

I'm using a custom workspace at the moment, before I tried a symlink from the default workspace to my webroot, when I did that it found the build file but failed when trying to run phing. I know it's a problem with permissions but I'm not sure exactly what.

I'm running this on a plesk web server and have tried adding the jenkins user to the psacln and psaserv groups but that didn't work either.

Comment: What do your folder permissions look like?

Answer (score 0):

I use hudson but I think is the same problem.

Provide to ant job the full path (advanced settings)

```
${WORKSPACE}/buil.xml
```

Assuming the correct set of jenkins user

```
RUN_AS_USER=jenkins
```

Go to the custom workspace and

```
chown -R jenkins:jenkins myworkspace
```

if it doesn't work

```
chmod -R 777 myworkspace
```

then you will fix later.

I hope it helps.